# How to fix the home screen captions in Illustrator 25.3?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I deleted some important files inside the Adobe Illustrator folder and I can't find them anymore.
Recently when I opened the Illustrator I faced these non-friendly captions on the Home screen.
Does anyone know how to fix it or the solution is just to reinstall it?

[image]

Comment: I just made a reinstall and everything is ok. Than you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be to uninstall and re-install illustrator, unless you can locate the file in your trash bin and place it where it needs to go.

Comment: probably wont do anything as uninstalling leaves the preferences intact. So there is a nontrivial chance that it will just be like that even after the uninstall reinstall cycle. I would start by renaming the prefs folder.

Comment: @joojaa - Adobe also has a [removal tool for creative cloud apps](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html) if there are more serious problems that aren't fixed by a reinstall.

Comment: @BillyKerr sure but you can just rename the Prefs folder too. and odds are it does everything in one step instead of 2. As a bonus you dont have to rebuild your prefs if neither of these actions help.